# Why my zuccinies have turned like this?

Tags: zucchini

In my garden the zuccinies look like this:

[image: My zu]

Also, once cooked they taste awfull. I tried to increase watering time and placed extra nozzles in my auto-watering system. Futherermore I placed calcium supplement in my plants as well. But still some of them are getting to look like this:

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong? Is that due to ants in my plant may cause some issues or not?
Is that due to nozzle misplacement as well?

Comment: Let them mature to 8-12".

Comment: That's not gonna help - they should be green and well formed even at 5 inches long,

Answer (score 1):

Given where you live, this seems like a silly question, but are your plants receiving 5 or 6 hours of full sun a day? I think this is a pollination problem, and lack of sunlight can cause that because pollinating insects prefer to forage in sunlight. Lack of enough pollinating insects can mean fruits are malformed, stunted from the blossom end as yours are. Given the extreme heat you had earlier this year, that also might have deterred pollinating insects, so that's another possibility. I'm afraid these malformed fruits will not improve in taste as time goes on. You might find this link https://savvygardening.com/zucchini-growing-problems/ interesting.

Comment: Sunlight is no issue. In Greece we have plenmty of them. Also we did haver a heatwave though.

Comment: Can I manually pollinate them using a cotton swab?

Comment: best to use a small paintbrush (like children's one or small make up brush) or even your finger - there's a guide to doing this in the link I provided above